# sparkjava and eclipse unresolved compilation problems:

Tags: java, java-8, spark-java

I have  followed the tut here http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spark</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spark</name>
  <description>spark</description>  
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Hello.java**

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

    public class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            get("/hello", (req, res)-> "Hello World");//eclipse error this line
        }
    }
```

I got an error with **eclipse**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    req cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token ",", . expected
    Syntax error on token "-", -- expected

    at Hello.main(Hello.java:5)
```

Comment: Can you post your Java and Eclipse versions, and compiler compliance level (in Eclipse package explorer, right click > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance level)?

Comment: here is the compliance level 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's lambda expressions are a feature in Java 8: [Oracle link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).  You'll need to change your compliance level (and java version, and pom) to java 8 to make this example compile.